# HSTS and redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, hsts

I was testing my website here https://hstspreload.org and I got this error:

> Error: HTTP redirects to www first
>
> http://example (HTTP) should immediately redirect to https://example
>   (HTTPS) before adding the www subdomain. Right now, the first redirect
>   is to https://www.example. The extra redirect is required to ensure
>   that any browser which supports HSTS will record the HSTS entry for
>   the top level domain, not just the subdomain.

As far as I can understand, the redirect, to be valid, should be done this way:

1. http://example (this is what the user enters in the address bar)
2. https://example (first redirect, to HTTPS)
3. https://www.example (second redirect, to subdomain www)

At the moment, this is my `htaccess` code causing the redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Is it possible/advisable to insert another redirect here? Are there any risks?

Any comment/advice/suggestion/rotten-tomato is appreciated  :-)

Comment: I see no issue with adding a second one.  The order you propose is correct.  So a user typing `http://example.com` will be redirect twice.  Once to `https://example.com`, then another to `https://www.example.com`.

Comment: @Nic3500 What's the best way to write it in the htaccess file? Do I simply add a rewriterule line or is there something better (more efficient, etc.)?

Comment: Yes, htaccess is a text file that you can edit.  Some tools exist, some providers force you to use one (or their own web page).  But if you have access, go for it!

Comment: I know what htaccess is   :-)   What I want to know is if is ok to simply add my rule before/after the current RewriteRule

Comment: The file is read top to bottom.  If you put `[L]` to the `RewriteRule` it will stop there.  So to respect the order you want, you will have to put the HTTPS rule first, then the www.

Comment: @Nic3500: if I simply add `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.it/$1 [R]` before the other `RewriteRule` I get an error "The page isn't redirecting properly". Moreover, in the address bar of the browser the URL is badly rewritten as the sum of two addresses (eg. https://www.example.com/https://example.com)

Comment: Add tag `[L]` to that first rule.  The client will be redirected twice.  Once for https, the other for www.  You do not run both rewrites at once.

Comment: But if I add L no further rule will be processed or am I missing something?

Comment: Indeed.  The sequence is: **1** client asks for `http://example.com` **2** you send 301 to `https://example.com`  **3** client comes back with `https://example.com` **4** you send 301 to `https://www.example.com` **5** client comes back with `https://www.example.com` **6** ok you let him in.  With this all cases are covered if the client comes in with something missing, your configuraiton always works.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I try it as soon as possible (if you add it as a reply, I can vote it and close the discussion)

Comment: It's the same, even with the [L]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary of the comments:

- Configuration in httpd.conf and .htaccess is read top to bottom.
- For RewritRules, they are applied in sequence, top to bottom, until you reach the last one.  All rules that match the condition are applied.
- To prevent that, *you can* add the `[L]` tag to a RewriteRule.  This tag says to Apache that it was the last rule to apply if it matches the conditions.  All further rules are ignored for this request.

The sequence of rewrites here is:

1. the client requests `http://example.com`
2. A RewriteRule redirects the client to `https://example.com`
3. The client comes back with `https://example.com`
4. A second RewriteRule redirects the client to `https://www.example.com`
5. The client comes back with `https://www.example.com`
6. No Rewriterule applies, Apache responds to the request.

Why do it this way?  It covers all cases.  If a client's first request is already `https://example.com`, the scenario above will start at step 4.

A sample configuration could look like:

```
Listen *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    [... OTHER CONFIGURATION ...]
</VirtualHost>

Listen *:443
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    [... OTHER CONFIGURATION ...]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I can't use any <VirtualHost>. Anyway, I solved here: https://serverfault.com/questions/930368/hsts-and-double-redirect/   :-)   THANKS!